# ASP.NET 5 (.NET CORE) Как проверить, существует ли файл по URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

есть проблема: не могу проверить, существует ли файл по URL на сервере. Нужно подключить фото пользователя `userphoto.jpg`, находящийся в папке `~/userscontent/avatars/`, а если такого файла нет -- вывести placeholder. В PHP это решается довольно-таки быстро, а здесь уже второй день бьюсь... Заранее спасибо

Comment: Для начала можете попробовать чисто клиентское решение: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32909488/6766879

Comment: Серверное решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63953734/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо это решает мой вопрос. Однако, возможно ли инкапсулировать серверное решение в статическую функцию?

Comment: Это ещё зачем? Статика — зло, пользуйтесь внедрением зависимостей

Comment: Кстати, позволять заливать заливать файлы на сервер, даже аватары - это потенциально плохая идея. Заливайте в какой-нибудь blob storage (если у вас Azure), или в S3 на амазон. или в базу, на крайний случай, с ограничением по размеру

Comment: @PashaPash, всё названное вами, конечно, хорошо и вполне справедливо, если бы не одно НО: это всё платное. А за бесплатный проект 400 руб/в мес и так много за хостинг.

Comment: @Alexander на бесплатный проект и у Azure и у Amazon есть free usage tier, которого с запасом хватит на десяток сайтов с аватарами :)

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо. Поизучаю.